# Incase of mutiple function definitions of a function in JavaScript, why the last implementation gets the preference?

Tags: javascript, function

In my experiments with Javascript functions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQIBE9DXUO2Y), I declared and defined 'myFunction()' 4 times and added this function to the click event of a button. In my observation I found the 4th implementation of 'myFunction()' is always called.

How does Javascript engine interprets and processes this code internally?

Can we override this default behavior? If yes, how?

*FYR Code*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "FIRST: Paragraph changed.";
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "SECOND: Paragraph changed.";
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "THIRD: Paragraph changed.";
}
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "FOURTH: Paragraph changed.";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Output*:

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have an exact answer but that makes sense.
The code is loaded sequentially and every declaration of the function overrides the previous one just like a variable assigned multiple time will override itself and the last assignment is the one that dominate.

Comment: Any idea or reference how browser JS engine interpretation works out. It's relatable to variable but functions have more semantic checks than vars to the best of my knowledge.